# cypress - compare two png images

Tags: javascript, cypress

The functionality is - after inputting some values in the UI, I will have an image download option and once download, I need to compare that PNG image with my base image which I already have in my cypress/fixtures/base/<nameOfTheFile.png>.

I am trying to make a utility function in cypress to compare two PNG images but I get issues one after another for all my approaches.

**Utils.js** (under integration folder)

```
const fs = require('fs');

export const comparePNGImages = (fileName) => {

    expect(fileName).to.be.a('string')

    const img1 = fs.readFileSync("./cypress/fixtures/baseImage/" + fileName);
    const img2 = fs.readFileSync("./cypress/fixtures/currentImage/" + fileName);

    expect(img1).to.matchImage(img2)

    return null;
}
```

and in **test**,

```
import { downloadPng, comparePNGImages } from './utils'
.........

var imageName = "SailingDirection.png";

//steps to input, download the image file, keep in fixtures folder
//.....

comparePNGImages(imageName)

.........
```

**Error in TestRunner:**

> fs.readFileSync is not a function

Note:

I tried to change the import statement to the following:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import { fs } from 'fs';
```

but none worked.

Also, read that fs will not have access to the local file system but surprisingly, the same `fs` stuff works in the same cypress project which is in other file plugins/index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
on('task', {
        validateTotalFileCount(folderName, expectedFileCount) {
            console.log("#### getTotalFileCount #### ");
            const length = fs.readdirSync(folderName).length;
            if (length == expectedFileCount) {
                throw new Error(`#### List of files not matched with expected count`)
            }
            return null;
        }
    })
```

Any help on this to fix it would be much appreciated.

Comment: use `cy.fixture('something.png').then( (fixture) => { do stuff with fixture })`